# "No properly configured Aurora Serverless clusters found." for use with AWS Amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify-cli, aws-aurora-serverless

I have set up an AWS Aurora Postgres DB server less v2 cluster in us-west-2 and also set up an iOS app with Amplify. I want to be able to query the DB from the app, but when I run `amplify api add-graphql-datasource`, I get the error  `No properly configured Aurora Serverless clusters found.`

The cluster allows me to run queries in the query editor just fine. And everything else in the amplify set up from https://docs.amplify.aws/swift/start/getting-started/installation/ worked, so I'm at a loss for what's wrong.

I doesn't give me any indication for what might be configured incorrectly and I can't seem to find any documentation on what is required in the config.

I suspect it's some kind of security/permissions things, but I'm new to AWS backend stuff, so it's all a black box to me.

Can someone help me understand what I might be doing wrong?